# Using joins to query by attribute on associated recored

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this horribly written query:

```
membership_ids = User.where(skip_membership_renewal: true).includes(:memberships).map(&:membership_ids).flatten
Memberships.where(id: membership_ids)
```

I have been trying to use `joins` so that I can just make one query.

```
Membership.includes(:user).where("user.skip_membership_renewal", true)
```

However, this doesn't work since I keep getting the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR`.

My relationship is:

```
User has_many :memberships
Membership belongs_to :user
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a pluralization error. In Rails, you define models as singular (`User`) and the database table is pluralized (`users`).

```
Membership.includes(:user).where("users.skip_membership_renewal" => true)
```

That said, you don't need to resort to using SQL literals for such a simple case. There are a bunch of other ways of assembling this query, like the scope option David Aldridge suggested, or either of these:

```
non_renewing_users = User.where(skip_membership_renewal: true)
Membership.joins(:user).merge(non_renewing_users)
Membership.where(user: non_renewing_users)
```

What's more is that these both only execute a single SQL query for most adapters because they use subqueries:

```
SELECT "memberships".*
FROM "memberships"
WHERE "memberships"."user_id" IN (
  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users"
  WHERE "users"."skip_membership_renewal" = true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably aim to use:

```
Membership.where(:user => User.skip_membership_renewal)
```

Add a scope onto User ...

```
def self.skip_membership_renewal
  where(skip_membership_renewal: true)
end
```

You should find that it runs as a single query.